# horizontally centering a tikz node on a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I have a `tikzpicture` environment containing multiple nodes. For the MWE example below, I have two nodes - an image and another node, placed to the left relative to the image.

If I use a simple `centering` command, the entire `tikzpicture` is horizontally centered across the page. However, what I would like to do is to have the image node horizontally centered across the page. How could I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

This line shows the width of the text across the page as a visual guideline how the image is centered horizontally on the page.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor = south west, inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\begin{scope}[x = {(image.south east)},y = {(image.north west)}]
\node [anchor=east] at (-0.05,0.5) {annotation};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How should I change the code, so that the x coordinate of `image.center` is horizontally centered on the page? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I' do it with `\useasboundingbox` command. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

This line shows the width of the text across the page as a visual guideline how the image is centered horizontally on the page.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west); % <-- to center wrt this rectangle
\node at (image.west) [left] {annotation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly.

Comment: @jopeto Please upvote and accept this answer to let the community know that you found what you needed.